# Changing the text of a tkinter LabelFrame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been struggling to get the text in the border of a tk.LabelFrame to change when I open a new text file inside the frame. I have been using essentially the same code as I use elsewhere to change a tk.Label.

I just came across this in some documentation:
"When a new labelframe is created, it has no default event bindings: labelframes are not intended to be interactive."

The last phrase is fairly definitive, but the use of the word 'default' makes me wonder if there is a way of achieving this.

So, my question is, can it be done?

Comment: you could use `Label.bind('key','function')` in order to make Label interactive .

Comment: @Ayyoub ESSADEQ thanks, but I'm trying to use a LabelFrame

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It would make it easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: All widgets have a `configure` method that can be used to reconfigure the widget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bryan Oakley who mentioned the magic word 'configure'which got me thinking along different lines and I came up with this solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('LabelFrame Demo')

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(
    root,
    text='text to change')

lf.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

def file_1_label():
    my_text = 'editing file 1'
    lf.configure(text='editing FILE 1')
    
def file_2_label():
    my_text = 'editing file 2'
    lf.configure(text='editing FILE 2')

button1 = tk.Button(lf, text='File 1')
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button1.configure(command=file_1_label)

button2 = tk.Button(lf, text='File2')
button2.grid(row=0, column=2)
button2.configure(command=file_2_label)

root.mainloop()
```